# Is there a way to get the location of the value extracted using an XPath expression in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML data that looks like below.

[image]

I have an xpath expression like //book/Price/Price2 that gives me the second price values for each book. I also want to know the location (line number and the position in the line) for each price that have extracted using the xpath expression. Can anyone suggest me the way to get that.

Comment: You can if you use the `Xml.Linq` classes, as `XElement` implements `IXmlLineInfo`, e.g. `((IXmlLineInfo) XDocument.Parse(@"<a><b>1</b></a>", LoadOptions.SetLineInfo).XPathSelectElement("/a/b")).LinePosition`. Adjust to your scenario as necessary. Note that the "old" DOM classes (`XmlDocument`, `XmlElement`) do not provide this data at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert how does that work if the element has an attribute and we query for the attribute value?

Comment: `XAttribute` implements `IXmlLineInfo` too, so you can do `(XmlLineInfo) (...XPathSelectElement(...).Attribute(...))`. If you have an XPath selecting *only* the attribute it gets a little more complicated since you have to use `XPathEvaluate` and a whole hoopla of casting (`(IXmlLineInfo) ((IEnumerable) (...XPathEvaluate(".../@attr")).Cast<XAttribute>().Single())`), quite clunky.